# how to create a drop down list with watermark text inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

In HTML how do you create a drop down list with water mark text inside the area.

My requirement is to have a drop down list look like a text box with watermark text, at the corner a down-word arrow for selecting the data from list.

```
<select>
  <option value="Class">Class room</option>
  <option value="Ground">Play ground</option>
</select>
```

This is giving me a normal dropdown list.
Drop down list box should like serach field in stackover flow with a arrow mark at end/corner.

Comment: @user2086641: I think you mean placeholder of watermark, yes?

Comment: offcourse you r right,placeholder with drop down list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need something like this:

**HTML:**

```
<select id="choice">
    <option value="0" selected="selected">Select...</option>
    <option value="1">Class room</option>
    <option value="2">Play ground</option>
</select>
```

**CSS:**

```
#choice option { color: black; }
.empty { color: gray; }
```

**JQuery:**

```
$("#choice").change(function () {
    if($(this).val() == "0") $(this).addClass("empty");
    else $(this).removeClass("empty")
});
$("#choice").change();
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Zmf6t/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can make in ul li like

```
<div>
<ul>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

give the li background image like

```
div ul li{background:url(arrow.png) no-repeat;}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using HTML 5, you can use placeholder attribute inside the text box.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Watermark" />
```

and use this jquery [autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#maxheight) to achieve drop down selection after entered a keyword.

Or

```
<select>
   <option value="" selected="selected">Watermark</option>
   <option value="Class">Class room</option>
   <option value="Ground">Play ground</option>
</select>
```